# Making doctrine ORM work on PHP

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have tried to follow the "steps" detailed on the website but i couldn't make it work:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

I have downloaded the doctrine package.
Then i have installed it using PEAR.

Now, i create a file called "test.php" with the following content:

```
//loding Setup from the doctrine package...
require 'vendor/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php';

Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();


use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array("/path/to/entities-or-mapping-files");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
'host'  => 'localhost',
    'user'     => 'admin',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'dbname'   => 'test',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

// or if you prefer yaml or xml
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
```

What else should i do to make it work?
I can not currently do something like:

```
 print_r($em->getRepository("User"));
```

It shows me many warnings, for example:

```
Class User does not exist and could not be loaded in 
Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ..../Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php
```

etc. The first one i guess is the key.

Something is missing but i dont know what.
Thanks.

Comment: As i wrote in there. I can not make something like print_r($em->getRepository("User")); because it shows me many warnings. For example: Class User does not exist and could not be loaded in

Comment: that's the point, we don't need to know you can't do it, we need to know why it doesn't work. Show your warning if you want help.

Comment: This is what i get when i try it: http://www.subirimagenes.com/privadas-capturadepantalla-1882946.html